# How do I manually update/evaluate cells that use "custom" formulas?

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I'm using [Refprop](https://www.nist.gov/srd/refprop) ([Documentation](https://www.nist.gov/sites/default/files/documents/2018/05/23/refprop10a.pdf)), tied into Excel, using [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to interact with the excel sheet. I'm writing a program that changes cell data, then retrieves the newly calculated output.

I'm having trouble updating/evaluating the cells that contain the formulas since the cells contain REFPROP formulas. Which I'm assuming is the problem. Is there a way to brute force the evaluations?

I only get this error when trying to evaluate formulas that are not excel-native. The error I get when trying to evaluate the cell is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Unused input [("Z",D24,"PT","E",D36,D37)] after attempting to parse the formula [[1]!REFPROP("Z",D24,"PT","E",D36,D37)]
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:2030)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getFormulaTokens(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:85)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:271)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(BaseXSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.BaseFormulaEvaluator.evaluate(BaseFormulaEvaluator.java:110)
    at GetCell.evaluateFormulas(GetCell.java:88)
    at GetCell.update(GetCell.java:70)
    at Main.main(Main.java:109)
```

The code I have tried to update the cell is:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(getCell("D41"));
evaluator.evaluate(getCell("D41"));
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Here's an example of a formula the cells use. In this case, this is the formula in cell D41. For reference I'm only trying to update cells D36 and D37 via Excel/Apache POI and get the output.

```
=REFPROP("Z",D24,"PT","E",D36,D37)
```

A side note is that the formulas update as expected when changing cells D36 and D37 in Excel itself, but not via Java/Apache POI.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Apache POI are you using? And if not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr I am using the most recent version -- 4.1.0-20190412

Comment: Since `REFPROP` is not a native Excel function but comes from an add in you need using [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) also in apache poi. If `REFPROP` comes from an add in, then the cell formula is `[1]!REFPROP("Z",D24,"PT","E",D36,D37)` where `[1]!` refers to the external link to the add in. And `apache poi` really throws `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Unused input`.

Comment: Seems `apache poi` is not able evaluating user defined functions which are coming from an add-in. In `XSSF` one could remove the add-in reference `\[\d{1,}\]!` form the formula  but in `HSSF` this is not possible.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks. So do I reset the equation using the regex you provided then try and re-evaluate?

Comment: Yes, but this is not all. Have you read [User Defined Functions](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html)? You also have to recreate the logic of the add-in user defined function using `Java` code. `Apache poi` does not interact with `Excel` in any kind. It only creates and/or uses `*.xlsx` files.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yikes I don't think that's going to be feasible in my time frame since REFPROP itself uses hundreds of external databases/configs and is written in fortran. Eventually I will have the time to implement everything properly. Thanks for your help